# Compare ISO time in JMETER assertion

Tags: api, groovy, jmeter

I am reading the measurements and I have 2 ISO time stamps.
Now using the JSON extractor, I have parsed the time into 2 variables namely "time1" and "time2"

Now I want to compare the time and decide which one is greater.

Sample time that I had parsed to the variables are like below,

time1: 2021-07-01T00:00:03Z

time2: 2021-07-01T00:00:02Z

Now I want to compare and print the value saying time1 is greater than time2 and the returned response is in descending order.

I tried the below snippet in JSR223:

```
String time1 = vars.get("time1");
String time2 = vars.get("time2");

OffsetDateTime created = OffsetDateTime.parse(time1);
OffsetDateTime updated = OffsetDateTime.parse(time2);
if (updated.isAfter(created)) {
    System.out.println("PASSED");
} else {
    System.out.println("FAILED");
}
```

Comment: And how has what you have tried failed? Could you please add the error, stacktrace, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example with `import` and using `log.info`

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
String time1 = vars.get("time1");
String time2 = vars.get("time2");

OffsetDateTime created = OffsetDateTime.parse(time1);
OffsetDateTime updated = OffsetDateTime.parse(time2);
if (updated.isAfter(created)) {
    log.info("PASSED");
} else {
    log.info("FAILED");
}
```